# Using head/tail function on pandas dataframe with different number of n for each group

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use head / tail function, but for each group i will take the different number of row according an input dictionary.

The function should have 2 input. First input is pandas dataframe

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"group":["A","A","A","B","B","B","B"],"value":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})
print(df)
  group value
0   A   0
1   A   1
2   A   2
3   B   3
4   B   4
5   B   5
6   B   6
```

Second input is dict :

```py
slice_per_group = {"A":1,"B":3}
```

Expected output :

```py
df.groupby('group').head(slice_per_group) #Obviously this doesn't work
  group value
0   A   0
3   B   3
4   B   4
5   B   5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `head` on each group separately:

```
df.groupby('group', group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g.head(slice_per_group.get(g.name)))

  group  value
0     A      0
3     B      3
4     B      4
5     B      5
```